# Is methyl phenyl sulfoxide optically active?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality, organosulfur-compounds

I am concerned about the stereogenic centres. But in this compound there is no chiral centres present. Sulphur is $\mathrm{sp^2}$-hybridized, so it cannot be chiral anyway. But I can see there is no symmetry present in this compound. Will this be a sufficient reason to tell the compound optically active?

[image]

Comment: This compound is in fact optically active as the sulfur has 4 different substituents, one of them being a lone pair.

Comment: That makes it _chiral_.  But if the lone pair can umbrella-invert like ammonia you do not see optical activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can heteroatoms with lone pairs be chiral centres?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50106/16683)