Is this aziridine compound chiral?

I am having a hard time assigning chirality to this molecule. It does not have stereocentres but still feels chiral because its mirror images do not superimpose and have no symmetry.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50106/can-heteroatoms-with-lone-pairs-be-chiral-centres

It may be chiral - aziridines have significant barrier of inversion, but it's tricky if this one would qualify too.

Things get murky with stuff like this, even solvent may be important.

Any chiral molecule lacks an improper axis of rotation $(S_n)$. I have attached different viewing angles of a 2,2-diphenylaziridine molecule (generated using Jmol). It can be observed that there is no $S_n$ symmetry here (it only possess the identity symmetry element). This tells you that the molecule alone is chiral.


However, this is only true if you had a pure sample of this molecule and if its structure does not change over a period of time. But, in a solution, this molecule does change its structure (picture attached below). This process is referred to as the nitrogen inversion (also called pyramidal inversion or fluxional process).


You can also check that this new inverted structure is a non-superimposable mirror image of the previous structure. Thus, they are enantiomers. So, in a solution, both of these enantiomers exist and thus you have a racemic mixture. Hence, the compound in solution loses its chiral properties over time due to racemisation.

Where is the stereocentre? Since, it is the inversion at the nitrogen centre that alters the chirality of the molecule, you can consider the nitrogen to be the stereocentre.
Assigning the chirality: Using the Cahn-Ingold-Prelog rules one can obtain the priority order of the atoms attached to the nitrogen (trigonal pyramidal centre). Also, note that the lone pair of electrons is replaced by a 'phantom atom' and is considered the least priority.
Consider the first molecule shown in this answer. The diphenyl- substituted carbon will be ranked $1$, the methylene carbon is ranked $2$, the hydrogen (bonded to N) is ranked $3$, and finally the lone pair (replaced by a 'phantom atom') is ranked $0$. Thus, the molecule is (R)-2,2-diphenylaziridine. The enantiomer (second molecule in this answer) takes the symbol (S).

References and Further Reading:

Martina, R.; Abeba, M. J.; Lattes, E. A. Aziridines. V. Etude Par Rmn de l’inversion de l’azote Dans Les Aziridines Symétriques à Fonetion Amine Secondaire. Journal of Heterocyclic Chemistry, 1973, 10, 91–94. https://doi.org/10.1002/jhet.5570100121.
Brückner, S.; Forni, A.; Moretti, I.; Torre, G. Absolute Configuration of a Chiral N-Chloroaziridine with Molecular Asymmetry Due Solely to a Trivalent Nitrogen Atom. X-Ray Structure of (R)-(–)-1-Chloro-2,2-Diphenylaziridine. J. Chem. Soc., Chem. Commun., 1982, 1218–1219. https://doi.org/10.1039/c39820001218.
Forni, A.; Moretti, I.; Torre, G.; Brückner, S.; Malpezzi, L.; Di Silvestro, G. Relationships between Solid-State Structures of Enantiomers and the Corresponding Racemic Compounds in Small Ring Derivatives. Comparison of Crystal Structures and Solid-State Properties of (R)-(–)- and Racemic 1-Chloro-2,2-Diphenylaziridine. Solvent Effect on the Racemization of (R)-(–)-1-Chloro-2,2-Diphenylaziridine. J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 2, 1984, 791–797. https://doi.org/10.1039/p29840000791.
Favre, H. A.; Powell, W. H. Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry, 2013. https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069. (The IUPAC Blue Book)


Not bad, but was there something more concrete, like proton exchange racemizing, or what's up with unsubstituted aziridines?

@Mithoron Oh yes, Ref. 1 does mention proton exchange racemising (they tried to eliminate water to observe the magnetic inequivalence). There were some papers that tried to study sterics as a factor but I don't recall it right now. Will update my answer later (or someone else could address it).
