# On what factors does amine inversion depend

Tags: amines

What factors promote amine inversion? Like bulky groups around the nitrogen atom or less sterically crowding groups?

Are there any other factors that affect amine inversion? Does the electronegativity of the atoms bonded to nitrogen affect amine inversion?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/what-causes-rapid-nitrogen-inversion